# Merging two databases without borking it

Tags: database, migration, import, export

Does anyone have a solution to the following issue:

I have a staging and production server. We've done work on staging but things have been changed on production so we can't just move the DB from ST->PR. Is there a plugin or some other solution that looks at all singular items and updates/overwrites that post only if the post is newer as a revision on production?

Answer (score 0):

This is a notoriously difficult thing to solve in WordPress because of how the database is constructed. I have since long given up on being able to merge dev -> staging -> prod.

Instead, I track any and all changes I make to the database in my dev environment, manually apply those to the production database when that time comes.

I know it's not a nice answer, but it's the only one you'll get when you need assurances that the DB won't be borked.